# How to find if range contains merged cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, range

I have an Excel document that contains duty shifts. I would like to findout if there is any merged cells like given below withing given range..

[image: Example]

How can I determine the cells are filled in given range or the cells are merged in given range?

```
If IsEmpty(Range("NewRange")) = False Then
    z = z + 1 'My counter 
End If
```

I tried IsEmpty Function but it doesnt work correctly on merged cells. You can try but the result is same.. While I got a block of empty cells there it counts as filled..

Comment: How is the `given range` defined? Do you want to check if an arbitrary range has any merged cells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS Excel 2010 and higher has [Range.MergeCells Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197310.aspx), which returns **true** if if the range contains merged cells.

Another method you'll find here: http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/find-merged-cells-in-excel/

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A9:G10")
With r
    If IsNull(.MergeCells) = True Or .MergeCells = True Then
        z = z + 1
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Actually, it only returns True if all the cells in the range are merged. It returns Null if there's a mixture.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. MSDN documentation does not mention that. So, the second link might be helpful ;)

Comment: Yea I tried this but no! It's not the solution. Still thanks.

Comment: How is it not the solution? Test if `mergecells` is Null or True - if so, there are merged cells.

Comment: You should perhaps have mentioned that somewhere in the original question then... ;)

Comment: @Rory I apologize it is working in a different way. I just need to define inside IsNull(.MergeCells) to get proper answer.. .MergeCells = Null wasnt working so I thought the function is kinda broken. Yep this is helpfull.